How to stop PipeWire from switching to HDMI audio
A lot of times when I connect an external screen, HDMI audio profile gets automatically re-enabled. Sometimes, even when screen wakes up after from powersaving mode while being connected. And many applications start to prefer HDMI audio instead of headphone output.
This is undesirable behaviour. I want HDMI audio profiles to stay off unless I re-enable them myself. How to configure PipeWire that way?
Alternatively, I'd be OK with "Headphones > HDMI audio > builtin speakers" output selection priority.
I'm using PipeWire 1.2.3. The distro is Gentoo Linux, I'm using i3 without any desktop environment.

Consider adding your distro and desktop environment. Not everything depends directly on the sound engine.
